# chrome extension sendMessages more than one

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**Hello** i'm trying to send message to popedup window, but when i close popup window end call it(from context menu) again.. it shows all last masseges..
**How can i send only one message only to new opened window?**

### Manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "1tst",
  "description": "sm txt",
  "version": "0.1",
  "author": "smwn",
  "permissions": [  
                    "activeTab",
                    "tabs",
                    "contextMenus"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["sample.js"]
  },
"content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["1.js"]
  }]
}
```

### sample.js

```
function genericOnClick(info, tab,selT) {
 var vid;
var nw_tb;

      chrome.tabs.create({
                url: chrome.extension.getURL('1.html'),
                active: false
            }, function(tab) {
            vid = tab.id;
                // After the tab has been created, open a window to inject the tab
                chrome.windows.create({
                    tabId: tab.id,
                    type: 'popup',
                    focused: true
                    // incognito, top, left, ...
                    },function(chromeWindow) {
                                //vid = chromeWindow.id;
                            }
                );
      });
      chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function(tabb){
        nw_tb = tabb.id;
        alert("vid: "+vid+" nw_tb: "+nw_tb);
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(vid, {statn: selT});
        return;
      });
}

var title = "Test '%s' menu item";
  var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":["selection"],
                                       "onclick": function(info,tab){   genericOnClick(info,tab, info.selectionText);}
                                      });
```

### 1.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>

</html>
```

### 1.js

```
window.onload=function(){
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
            console.log(sender.tab ?
                        "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                        "from the extension");
            sendResponse({metroSTAT: "OK"});
            alert(request.statn);
       });
}
```

Comment: Where is `genericOnClick()` invoked ? Please, post the whole code (or at least all relevant parts).

Comment: Maybe put all the code at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) could help ?

Comment: ups.. my mistake.. i was update the code "sample.js". i uploaded it https://db.tt/MOXkKcH5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The problem

Every time `genericOnClick()` is called, it registers a new listener for the `windows.onCreated` event. Once registered, the listeners will trigger every time.

#### The solution

One of the many possible solutions is to "un-register" the listener once it is triggered for the first time (using **[`removeListener()`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events.html#method-Event-removeListener)**):

```
// Replace the following block:
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function(tabb){
    ...
});

// With this:
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function tmpListener(tabb) {
    chrome.windows.onCreated.removeListener(tmpListener);
    ...
});
```

Comment: [`activeTab`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab.html) is not a subset of `tabs`. Compare [What activeTab allows](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab.html#what-activeTab-allows) with [tabs permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#manifest).